# set created role to user in Plone

Tags: plone

I am using Plone 4.
How to set custom role through code in plone.
I have created a role "normaluser". i am able to assign this role to user throgh site setup-> users and groups .It is working fine.

How to set this role "normaluser" to a user via code?

Comment: Do you need of a custom role rather than customizing permissions allowed to a role ?

Answer (score 3):

You may use [plone.api](http://docs.plone.org/4/en/external/plone.api/docs/user.html)

```
from plone import api
api.user.grant_roles(username='jane',
    roles=['normaluser',]
)
```

Add `obj` parameter if you want to assign the role locally on a specific object.